# Is it normal to see all of this while installing Vue JS CLI?

Tags: windows, vue.js, npm, installation, vuejs3

I just need to know why am i getting all these warnings and vulnerabilities after i run (npm install -g @vue/cli) to install Vue JS 3 globally on windows.

[A picture of the warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0OnN.png)

Comment: As it was suggested in previous questions, this is perfectly normal and should be ignored. You're getting these warnings because we live in imperfect world where package maintainers are unable to keep their dependencies up to date for the sake of pleasing NPM's audit system, and the latter provides no way to distinguish between vulnerabilities and "vulnerabilities".

Comment: Got it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to answer my own question, it's perfectly normal to see those and they should be ignored as Estus Flask answered